# How to make a preview / duplicate of a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget `UnkownWidget()` (let's say the sample counter from Flutter) :

[image]

What I would like to create is a widget that displays its child next to a duplication of its view:

```dart
WithPreviewOnTheRight(
  child: UnknownWidget(),
),
```

What I would like `WithPreviewOnTheRight` to do is to display its child on the left, and a preview/screening/duplication on the right:

I want the 2 instances to be *"the same"* (aka sharing the same state). When I interact with the widget on the left, the changes are also visible on the widget on the right.

[image]

The widget on the right doesn't have to be interactive, I am planning to wrap it with an [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html). I just want it to be a *"rediffusion"* / *"screening"*  of the main one on the left.

Using a `Row` as in

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: child,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: child,
    ),
  ],
),
```

wouldn't work as the 2 *"views"* wouldn't share the same state.

---

How can I duplicate the *"view"* of a widget?

Comment: The simplest way to do this would probably be to use state management to mirror the same underlying state across both widgets.

Comment: I don't have access to the state of `UnknownWidget` though, it could be anything, like a widget from a library or a widget of the dev using my own package

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to paint the child another time, next to the old one. And you won't be able to interact with the second one.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class DoubleWidget extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const DoubleWidget({super.key, required super.child});

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return DoubleRenderObject();
  }
}

class DoubleRenderObject extends RenderShiftedBox {
  DoubleRenderObject({RenderBox? child}) : super(child);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    final child = this.child!;
    final childConstraints = BoxConstraints(
      maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth / 2,
      minWidth: constraints.minWidth / 2,
      minHeight: constraints.minHeight,
      maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
    );
    child.layout(childConstraints, parentUsesSize: true);
    size = Size(child.size.width * 2, child.size.height);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    super.paint(context, offset);
    super.paint(context, offset + Offset(child!.size.width, 0));
  }

  @override
  double computeMinIntrinsicWidth(double height) {
    return (child?.getMinIntrinsicWidth(height) ?? 0.0) * 2;
  }

  @override
  double computeMaxIntrinsicWidth(double height) {
    return (child?.getMaxIntrinsicWidth(height) ?? 0.0) * 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's see if I understood what you want to achieve.

The **Widget** approach:
Create a widget class for your component, which you can call multiple instances which might not be entirely disconnected between them, if you have a common controller that is used to set their state, making them clones of each other.

```
class EmptyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const EmptyScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("title"),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Flexible(flex: 1, child: Text('Content')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The **Method** approach: 
Just like before, but instead of creating a class, you create a function that returns the Widget.
These methods might create an exact clone of the element that you want, without the Widget state management part in it.

```
 Widget EmptyScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("title"),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Flexible(flex: 1, child: Text('Content')),
      ),
    );
  }
```

in both approaches, you can call the element by writing `EmptyScreen()` on your widget tree.

Just be aware that any constraints like height, and width are not set by default, and might depend on the parent of the element where you place your self-made widgets.

To make sure both have the same aspect, you might need to track the size of one of them, and manually set the values of the clone.

I hope this helped.

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand. Do you want me to call your method `EmptyScreen()` twice and put the results in a `Row`? That would be 2 different instances and the interactions on the 1st instance won't be reflected on the 2nd instance. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Both Widget and Method(or function) work in a similar way. 
You can call it as many times as you want. The advantage of the StatelessWidget is that you can define a state to control the behavior of all the clones.